# cypress viewport not rendering all content missing checkboxes , order details while checking out. It shows correct on a normal browser

Tags: php, automation, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Cypress viewport not rendering all content from the website. missing checkboxes , package details while checking out .It shows correct on a normal browser where all the information appears but not on the cypress viewport.

This is what I see in cypress viewport for all browsers:
[cypress viewport missing checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HY0jC.png)

THis is what I see in an actual browser which is correct also
[Checkbox should be there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXkML.png)

Any help to fix that, please.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the code or script that exhibits the problem referenced by your question.

Comment: @JohnH Added screenshot which will give a better idea to understand the problem. thanks